# Count of consolidated lines and Hash value - getting the remainder in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have an input XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
      <entry>
             <ID>T-1149</ID>
             <Item_ID>FM1</Item_ID>
             <Item_Amount>
                        <Amount>20.00</Amount>
             </Item_Amount>
      </entry>
      <entry>
             <ID>T-1149</ID>
             <Item_ID>FM1</Item_ID>
             <Item_Amount>
                         <Amount>10.00</Amount>
             </Item_Amount>
      </entry>
      <entry>
             <ID>T-1142</ID>
             <Item_ID>FM1</Item_ID>
             <Item_Amount>
                          <Amount>10.00</Amount>
             </Item_Amount>
      </entry>
      <entry>
             <ID>T-1142</ID>
             <Item_ID>FM2</Item_ID>
             <Item_Amount>
                         <Amount>-50.00</Amount>
             </Item_Amount>
      </entry>
</root>
```

The requirements are:

1. Consolidate the entry if they have the same ID and Item_ID, and sum the total amount. Count the number of lines in the output including header and trailer.
2. Get the Hash total value based on the ID and Amount. The algorithm is: 
   (1) Determine the position. 
   ID is right align with Char(30) field length 
   Amount is left align with Sign(27) field length 
   (2) Transform each alphanumeric character or sign value into a number. Below is the sample mapping of characters.
   T = 30, - = 42, . = 41, space = 40 
   (3)  Split ID field into two portions : 
   •   Value A (15 alphanumeric value) - add up the transformed numbers from position 1 - 15 
   •   Value B (15 alphanumeric value) - add up the transformed numbers from position 16 - 30 
   (4)  Split Amount field into two portions : 
   •   Value C (15 sign value) - add up the transformed numbers from position 1 - 15 
   •   Value D (12 sign value) - add up the transformed numbers from position 16 - 27 
   (5) Then apply the formula: REMAINDER = mod (abs( (B + D) - (A + C) ),  13) 
   (6) hashed total = Sum of all REMAINDER.

The output which is a fixed width should look like this:

```
Header1
T-1149                        FM1                      30.00
T-1142                        FM1                      10.00
T-1142                        FM2                     -50.00
TRAILER 5 15
```

Where 5 is the overall count of lines incl. header and trailer and 15 is the hash total.

Sample computation for the first entry:

```
T-1149 
VALUE A: 30+42+1+1+4+9+40*9 =447
VALUE B: 40*15 = 600
VALUE C: 40*15 = 600
VALUE D: 3+41+40*7= 324
REMAINDER=6
```

I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>


    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="#all"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="A" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="root/entry/ID" phase="end"
            select="accumulator-after('values') => subsequence(1, 15) => sum()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="B" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="root/entry/ID" phase="end"
            select="accumulator-after('values') => subsequence(16, 27) => sum()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="C" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule
            match="root/entry/Item_Amomunt/Amount"
            phase="end" select="accumulator-after('values') => subsequence(1, 15) => sum()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="D" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule
         match="root/entry/Item_Amomunt/Amount"
            phase="end" select="accumulator-after('values') => subsequence(16, 27) => sum()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="values" as="xs:integer*" initial-value="()">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="entry" select="()"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule
            match="entry/ID/text() | entry/Item_Amount/Amount/text()"
            select="
                analyze-string(., '.')//*:match ! (
                if (. = '.')
                then
                    41
                else
                    if (. = ' ')
                    then
                        40
                    else
                        if (. = '-')
                        then
                            42
                        else
                            if (. = ',')
                            then
                                42
                         else
                            if (. = 'T')
                            then
                               30 
                            else
                                xs:integer(.))"
        />
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="remainder" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="root/entry" select="()"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule
            match="root/entry" phase="end"
            select="
                abs((accumulator-after('B') + accumulator-after('D')) -
                (accumulator-after('A') + accumulator-after('C'))) mod 13"
        />
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="remainder-sum" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="root" select="0"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="root/entry"
            select="$value + accumulator-after('remainder')"/>
    </xsl:accumulator> 

    <xsl:variable name="count_invoice_line"
        select="count(root/entry)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="header_line">
        <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="trailer_line">
        <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
    </xsl:variable> 


    <xsl:variable name="RightPadding"
        select="'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     '"/>

    <xsl:variable name="LeftPadding"
        select="'                                                                                         
    '"/>
    <xsl:function name="mf:PadLeft">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:param name="length"/>
        <xsl:variable name="leftPad">
            <xsl:value-of
                select="substring($LeftPadding, 1, $length - string-length(string($string)))"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="concat($leftPad, $string)"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="mf:PadRight">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:param name="length"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="substring(concat($string, $RightPadding), 1, $length)"/>
    </xsl:function>
    <xsl:template match="/">

       <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:sequence
        select="accumulator-after('remainder-sum')"/>
        <Control_Header_Record>
            <RowIdentifier>
                <xsl:value-of select="mf:PadRight('HEADER', 6)"/>
            </RowIdentifier>          
        </Control_Header_Record>
        <Detail>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="root/entry"
                group-by="concat(ID, ' ', Item_ID)">
                  <ID><xsl:value-of select="mf:PadRight(ID, 30)"/></ID>
                  <Item_ID><xsl:value-of select="mf:PadRight(Item_ID, 3)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="mf:PadLeft(Amount, 27)"/>
                </Row_Indentifier>

        </Detail>
        <Trailer_Record>
            <xsl:variable name="total_feed_line">
                <xsl:value-of select="$count_invoice_line + $header_line + $trailer_line"/>
            </xsl:variable>          
            <RowIdentifier><xsl:value-of select="mf:PadRight('TRAILER',8)"/></RowIdentifier>
            <Total_Feed_Line><xsl:value-of select="mf:PadRight($total_feed_line,2)"/></Total_Feed_Line>
            <Hash_Total_Value><xsl:value-of select="mf:PadRight($remainder-sum,15)"/></Hash_Total_Value>
        </Trailer_Record>
     </xsl:template>
```

The problem with the codes are: 
1. It doesnt get the correct total lines in the trailer. When two rows are consolidated into one row, it is still counting the item as two because it it is basing on the "root/entry" xpath. I tried creating a variable and assign a number to it inside the loop but it's not adding properly. Something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="counter"/>  <-- Global variable
<xsl:value-of select="$counter + 1"> <-- inside the loop
<xsl:value-of select=$counter> <-- added in the trailer
```

2. The hash value is not adding the "space" for computation. Example, If I have T-1149, it is summing up the numbers but not the space from position 7 to 15.

   T-1149 
   VALUE A: 30+42+1+1+4+9 =89
   VALUE B: 0
   VALUE C: 0
   VALUE D: 3+41= 44
   REMAINDER=6

I tried creating a variable and put it into the accumulator instead of the node but it isn't working. For instance,

```
<xsl:variable name="var1" select="1149                          "/>
<xsl:variable name="var2" select="                      12.00"/>

<xsl:accumulator name="A" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="$var1" phase="end"
        select="accumulator-after('values') => subsequence(1, 15) => sum()"/>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

I'm planning to transform the input file first (from another stylesheet) to format and add the space and input it into the main stylesheet but the problem is to how to put a variable inside the accumulator rule instead of the node. Can it be done the same stylesheet and in XSLT2.0? I'm not familiar with XSLT3. Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you group your content and then apply accumulators on the grouped result I think you are more likely to have a meaningful result. Of course accumulators are just one way to compute values, you can also consider writing functions with `xsl:function`. But the main issue seems to be that you want to group and then apply computations, whether done with functions or accumulators, on the grouping result so you need to put the grouping result in a variable and process the variable if you want to use accumulators.

Comment: Hi @Martin, i've tried putting the for each into a variable and call the element to compute the count but I’m getting complilation error saying a variable with no following sibling instructions has no effect and then variable has not been declared.
<xsl:variable name="rows" as="element(row)*">
//for each code here
 </variable>
<xsl:value-of select="count($rows)"/>,

Comment: also, How can I insert a variable in the accumulator-rule? It seems like its not accepting variable but the context item is should just be a node in the Match params. The purpose of the variable is to put the formatted values with spaces. 
<xsl:accumulator name="A" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="$formattedID" phase="end"
            select="accumulator-after('values') => subsequence(1, 15) => sum()"/>. Kind of stuck here :( thank you..

Comment: You will need to break that problem down into smaller problems and post each as a separate question with minimal but complete samples and the exact error description. If you are struggling with the grouping ask about that separately. As for putting a variable into a match pattern of an accumulator, I am afraid I don't understand what you want to achieve with that. It seems to be a misconception on what accumulators can be used for.

Comment: Hi @Martin, thanks for the response. I have posted a new question about the grouping https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59925295/count-the-lines-after-grouping-data-in-xslt

Comment: Hi @Martin, for the hash total value count, my main issue is that the current code (that uses accumulator match=""...) only sees what it is in the xml file. For instance, I have this <ID>1234</ID>, when I put this node in the accumulator match, it is just summing up the number in the node. What I want to achieve is that, I want the ID to look like this <ID>1234                          </ID> (PS i've added 26 spaces in the ID,its not showing aftr comment,IDfield length is 30)& put this this in the accumulator match so that space will be added in the computations based on the code shown above.

Comment: I did try to answer that separate question about the grouping but you have not in any way indicated there whether it solves the grouping problem. The result you get there from the grouping can be fed to your existing code using accumulators, if that code works.